# epoch time in Android differes from PHP

Tags: java, php, android, time

My php code :

```
   echo time();

   ----->  1427313418
```

My java (android) code :

```
   String current_in_sec = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)+""; // to convert it to seconds.
   Log.i("Log",current_in_sec);

    ---->  1427306783
```

Notice in php  :  1427**313**783 , vs java 1427**306**418

I know that php returns time in seconds , while java returns time in millies , so I devided Java result by 1000 .

As you can see , the differences is not about milli seconds , it seems they are very different ( about 2 hours maybe );

And in php I used this :

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

But it doesn't make any difference ;

Any guess ?

Hint :

I tried not to divide Java result by 1000 , here is the result :

```
   String current_in_sec = (System.currentTimeMillis())+""; 
   Log.i("Log",current_in_sec);

    ---->  1427307978601
```

As you can see again 1427**307**978601  , The **BOLD** part is far different from php result;

This tests are in my Laptop:

myLaptop->Android studio->genymotion

myLaptop->(PHP+Apache)->SublimeText

Comment: are the 2 pieces of code running on the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genymotion emulator is set to wrong timezone. Go to the Android settings, and set correct location/timezone. I had the same problem before.
Also, set it manually, **not from internet**.

[image]

Comment: Hmm , But I cant find any time-related-settings in gennymotion , And This is epoch time , I think it's not related to timezone :(

Comment: @xe4me, In running emulator device, not genymotion itself.

Comment: Thanks , it worked , But this is wierd , So Any different android device may have different timezone , So what's the point of Epoch time anyway ?

Comment: @xe4me, Yes, it just system of counting time. You must check timezone, and convert it to UTC.
`There is ony one Unix time and it is created by using the UTC/GMT time zone. This means you might have convert time zones to calculate timestamps.` - http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php

Comment: Interesting , So I should Write a Code in my Android which detects devices timezone , Then I should Convert that to my desired(UTC) timezone , Am I right ?

Comment: @xe4me, Yes, you should check, if a current Android Device is using the same timezone, as your server. And if not - convert it to UTC. You can use [getOffset(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset(long)) to detect offset from UTC.